# maven-war plugin war generating time

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-war-plugin

maven-war pluging used in my project performs below operations as part of build process and creating war.

1. Exploding webApp
2. Assembling webApp {project's webapp module} into the directory (target directory) with {project's webapp module-1.0.0-snapshot version)
3. Copy webApp webResources to the directory (target directory)
4. Generating war into target directory
5. Building war into target directory

finally below folders will be there once the build finishes in the target directory will have below folders along with project.war which is the only thing I will need to deploy
1)classes 
2)generated-sources
3)some xmls (checkstyle related and others which are at root level)
4)webappModule-snapshot-source.jar
5)webappModule-snaphot-test-source.jar
6) and finally the actual war file

The above process collectively takes more than 40 mins. I was wondering if I could avoid some of these steps like copy webApp webResources into the target directory, generating two jar files as I mentioned below and likewise to reduce this war creation time. If yes, how can I do that ? I will mention how the maven-war-plugin is defined in pom.xml.

```
<plugins>
  <plugin>
   <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.2</version>
   <warName>projectName</warName>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Please suggest if we can add some goals to reduce this time or overall build time. I am using parallel build already.

Comment: I had to check how old the given version of maven-war-plugin really is. It is **14 years** old. Please upgrade to the most recent version https://maven.apache.org/plugins/ Furthermore I suppose other plugins in your build are very old as well ...so please check them with the most recent versions..Furthermore the given tag `<warName>..</warName>` does not exist at this position. It's part of the configuration of plugin please check the documentation https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html..please add your log output ...

Comment: Thanks for your response .I can try upgrading it , also can I skip any of the steps mentioned during explodding webapp and war creation process , specially the third step which copy of webApp webResources to the target directory , this step of copy consumes lot of time.

Comment: and yes "war name" tag is inside configuration .

Comment: One workaround did work for me which is excluding node_modules to be copied in war , this has significantly reduced the build time by 25 mins. However, I haven't tested my war yet to see if it works or not . Is it necessary to have node_modules present in the war file ?

Comment: I can not answer the question if the node_modules are necessary in your application. The only person who can answer this is: You. Furthermore running a build for 15 minutes is a lot. How many classes/dependencies do you have and how large is the war in the end?